# Haskell Stack Resolver error just trying to run ghci

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm a haskell newcomer, I've tried googling, IRC, and doing what the CLI tells me to do, but can't seem to get basic haskell ecosystem tools to play nice.

I installed ghc, stack, and cabal via the minimal installers OSX link on this page https://www.haskell.org/downloads and now I'm running into some strange resolver problems while trying to get started with stack. I run `stack ghci` it tells me that it wants 7.10.3 and to run `stack setup`. Setup then says it installed ghc@7.10.2. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Try remove everything and install stack only. If you have homebrew run `brew install haskell-stack` and `stack setup` will install everything including ghc and cabal for you.

Comment: I didn't install via brew, I installed via the manual download. Apparently the version of stack in that package is `0.1.0.2` which is super old, and this bug is very dated. I don't know why the .org downloads page installs an ancient version of the tool, but my fix ended up being to download stack manually from here: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/blob/master/doc/install_and_upgrade.md and then once I downloaded the zip I ran `mv ~/Downloads/stack-1.0.2-osx-x86_64/stack /Applications/ghc-7.10.2.app/Contents/bin/stack` to put the updated stack in place of the old one. Seems to work!

Comment: The old version is actually `0.1.2.0`, typo

Comment: The homepage of other languages are usually maintained by compiler team and / or big companies, while the homepage of haskell is maintained by volunteers. So almost everything on www.haskell.org is outdated. They still recommend MinGHC for installation on windows but if you click the link you will see **"MinGHC is dead. Please use Stack."** in bold and big font. You'd better stick with the community for latest news (by community I mean /r/haskell, haskell-cafe and here).

Comment: @nackjicholson can you add your comment as an answer? (maybe including what zakyggaps said)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the version of stack in that package is 0.1.2.0 which is super old, and this bug is very dated. I don't know why the .org downloads page installs an ancient version of the tool, but my fix ended up being to download stack manually from here: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/blob/master/doc/install_and_upgrade.md and then once I downloaded the zip I ran

```
mv ~/Downloads/stack-1.0.2-osx-x86_64/stack /Applications/ghc-7.10.2.app/Contents/bin/stack
```

That command puts the updated stack in place of the old one and things then seem to work!

As a note: Learning more about installing haskell, it seems everyone suggests that you never install haskell via haskell.org but instead install stack on it's own and use it to install haskell.